# How to force explicit naming and position of Powershell function parameters?

Tags: powershell

I have a function defined as follows:

```
function foo {
    [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)] param([string]$a, [string]$b)
    if ($a -eq 'aaa' -and $b -eq 'bbb') {
        # Do stuff
    }
}
```

Currently, the parameters must be named for the function call to work, but their positions are irrelevant. How can I also force their position in the function call, so that `foo -a aaa -b bbb` works, but `foo -b bbb -a aaa` doesn't.

Comment: You can't. Why would you?

Comment: [1] you cannot do that. [*grin*] ///// [2] what is the problem you are trying to solve with that [peculiar] requirement?

Comment: Maybe he's indirectly asking for `splatting', or, `[string[]]` instead of two params

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Fair enough, I was purely interested in whether or not this was possible. I understand that it isn't, thanks!